# How to update ag-grid versions?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Previously I used:

- "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
- "ag-grid-angular": "^18.1.1"
- "ag-grid-enterprise": "^18.1.1" version.

Since the licence was expired I got the new version licences.

And then I added:

- "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^22.1.1",
- "@ag-grid-community/core": "^22.1.1",
- "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^22.1.1",
- "@ag-grid-enterprise/core": "^22.1.1",
- "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^22.1.1",

And also I added

```
@import "./node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.scss";
@import "./node_modules/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham/sass/ag-theme-balham.scss";
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

to **styles.css** file.

But row lines are missed in ag-grid for an updated version.[image: image description here]

If you can give me suggestions it will be a great help for me.

This is another image of ag-grid.
[image]

Comment: What data is there in `row lines` ?  Can you provide some code for reference

Comment: <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 500px; row-gap: 30px;" rowStyle="height:50px;"
                class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
                [animateRows]="true" rowSelection="multiple" [floatingFilter]="true" 
                (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" rowHeight="25" [modules]="modules">
                </ag-grid-angular>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps...my package.json looks slightly different than yours:

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^22.1.1",
"ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^22.1.1",
```

Comment: Yes this is the correct approach to have all the enterprise features available within an Angular application. More details can be seen here: https://blog.ag-grid.com/minimising-bundle-size/

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to upgrade "ag-grid": "^18.1.2", to "ag-grid-angular": "^20.1.0", to do so you need to follow changes

Step1: go to package.json and modify "ag-grid": "^18.1.2", to "ag-grid-angular": "20.1.0",

Step2: change your typescript version "typescript": "~2.7.2" to "typescript": "~3.2.4"

Step3: Run npm update in your project.

Step4: now run ng serve